# Gallio: Cannot run tests because the MSTest executable was not found

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, gallio

I installed the newest Gallio release 3.2.603 on a box without Visual Studio that will be our CI server. The NAnt script successfully built the .Net 4.0 projects but when it tries to run MSTest tests the following error occurs.

[gallio] Gallio NAnt Task - Version 3.2 build 601

[gallio] [error] Assembly XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[gallio] Cannot run tests because the MSTest executable was not found

Am I wrong to expect that Gallio is able to run MSTest tests without the MSTest executable or any other Visual Studio components installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I got an answer from Gallio support that it actually requires MSTest.exe to be present on the box. I'll test the package that Aseem suggested whether it provides enough stuff to run the tests.

**Update**: I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Test Agent 2010 from the package. I had to add the string value InstallDir to [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0] and set the value to something like
“C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE”

Now my CI box runs those tests perfectly.

Comment: Do you by chance know if installing Test Agent 2010 will allow Gallio to run coded ui tests?

Comment: No need to install anything. Just add the mentioned registry key. See: https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/master/src/Extensions/MSTest/Gallio.MSTestAdapter/Wrapper/MSTestResolver.cs

Answer (score 5):

I dont know anything about Gallio, but just wanted to share that with visual studio 2010, you dont really need visual studio to run MSTest tests. You can simply install test agent (a very light-weight sku) which additionally installs MSTest. This test agent installer can be installed from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=A3216D2A-0530-4F6C-A7C9-0DF37C54A902).

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed this worked for me.  Running Sonar on a box with VS2010.  Sonar could not find MSTest until I added this registry value.

Comment: I did precisely as Ivan stated in his update, with the exception of having VS2010 installed entirely, but the paths were still the same.