# sonar / maven context: Gallio execution failed. Searching why:?

Tags: .net, maven, sonarqube, gallio

I've got a server 2008 continuous integration box, on which I want to use Gallio so as to execute my MSTests and PartCover for my Sonar dashboard.

I installed Gallio 3.3.1 x64 along with PartCover, and so on.

Gallio works via Icarus on my test assemblies (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883180/gallio-cannot-run-tests-because-the-mstest-executable-was-not-found) answer)

However, through Sonar, I've got this puzzling log trace (see bellow). Even though my tests assemblies are qualified as test project, the error message for Gallio is

```
'Embedded error: Gallio execution failed.
No test assembly was found. Please check your project's Gallio plugin configuration.'
```

Any idea on how to track and fix this issue?

Thanks,

**Note:** I could not for some reasons post this question on the Gallio-user group, so I try there.

```
[INFO] Execute: org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:2.11:sonar
[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-sonar}]
[INFO]  Database dialect class org.sonar.jpa.dialect.Derby
[INFO]  Initializing Hibernate
[INFO]  The following 'sln' file has been found and will be used: D:\toto.sln
[INFO]  The project 'toto.Test' has been qualified as a test project.
[INFO]  The project 'titi.Test' has been qualified as a test project.

[INFO]  -------------  Analyzing toto
[INFO]  Selected quality profile : [name=Sonar C# Way,language=cs]
[INFO]  Configure maven plugins...
[INFO]  Compare to previous analysis (2011-11-30)
[INFO]  Compare over 5 days (2011-11-25, analysis of 2011-11-29 10:52:11.443)
[INFO]  Compare over 30 days (2011-10-31, analysis of 2011-11-29 10:52:11.443)
[INFO]  Initializer CSharpProjectInitializer...
[INFO]  Initializer CSharpProjectInitializer done: 6 ms
[INFO]  Skipping the non generated assembly of project : toto
[INFO]  No assembly to check with Gendarme
[INFO]  Skipping the non generated assembly of project : toto
[INFO]  No assembly to check with FxCop
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.CSharpSourceImporter@1acc1c2...
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.CSharpSourceImporter@1acc1c2 done: 116 ms
[INFO]  Sensor com.sonar.plugins.csharp.squid.C@caf6e7...
[INFO]  Sensor com.sonar.plugins.csharp.squid.C@caf6e7 done: 233 ms
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gallio.GallioSensor@1b4bc2a...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Gallio execution failed.
No test assembly was found. Please check your project's Gallio plugin configuration.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at ...
```

Here's the POM, if ever needed:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>totoGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>toto</artifactId>
  <name>TOTO</name>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>netpack</packaging>

    <profiles> 
 <profile>
      <id>sonar-dotnet</id>
      <activation>
        <!-- Optional activation by default -->
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <!-- Location of the the .Net installations (pick the one you need) -->
        <dotnet.4.0.sdk.directory>C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319</dotnet.4.0.sdk.directory>
        <fxcop.directory>C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Fxcop 10.0</fxcop.directory>
        <partcover.directory>C:\Program Files (x86)\PartCover\PartCover .NET 4.0</partcover.directory>
        <sourcemonitor.directory>C:/Program Files (x86)/SourceMonitor</sourcemonitor.directory>
        <stylecop.directory>C:\Program Files (x86)\StyleCop 4.6</stylecop.directory>

        <sonar.host.url>http://10.101.99.198:20000</sonar.host.url>

      </properties>
   </profile>

   </profiles>

  <properties>
        <sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file>toto.sln</sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file>
    <sonar.dotnet.version>4.0</sonar.dotnet.version>
    <sonar.language>cs</sonar.language>
    <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dotnet-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <language>cs</language>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Since this is tagged maven, is there a `pom.xml` file?  If so, can you post relevant snippet?

Comment: indeed, there's a POM. I'll add it

Comment: Workaround so far: launch PartCover as a batch command in my Jenkins project, then call Gallio in 'reuseReport' mode

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue is?

Comment: No, I did not. Gallio in reuseReport is currently the solution in production.

Comment: Thanks @Vinzz !!! setting sonar.gallio.mode= to 'reuseReport' seemed to work for me.

Comment: @Vinzz ...actually after closer inspection, using 'reuseReport' just seem to ignored all my tests. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fount it (thanks for Fabrice Bellingard on the sunar_user mailing list), his own words:

> OK, you are building the project with the "Release" build
>   configuration, so as you can see in Jenkins log, the compiled
>   assemblies end up in the "bin/release" folder. However, you run the
>   Sonar analysis with the default parameters, and so the C# Plugins look
>   into "bin/Debug" folder to find assemblies.
>
> So you have 2 solutions: •    either you compile the project with the
>   "Debug" build configuration • or you specify the following property
>   for the sonar analysis: "sonar.dotnet.buildConfigurations=Release"
>   (see doc for that property on the Wiki)