# Running MSTests on TeamCity build server without Visual Studio installed

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, mstest

I'd like to get MSTests working in TeamCity without having to install visual studio on the build agent.  I'm looking to see if anyone has accomplished this or has any insight into how to make it happen.

Comment: @Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954943/how-to-use-mstest-in-continous-integration-without-vs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone revisits this - they have introduced Visual Studio Agents that includes a standalone version of mstest
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334

Comment: I can verify that Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 is now available and works just fine with TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* MSTest.exe can be run as a standalone process.  While it's not ideal, you can try copying the executable out of your VS install, and onto your build server (it can be found in [Install Base]\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE)

I haven't tried this, so keep that in mind.  It may take some trial and error to carry over any dependencies that the app may need, but I don't see any reason why you can't get it to work (eventually).

Comment: Doesnt work - there are surprisingly (insanely) many dependencies. See one of the many duplicates of this question. But fair play for declarign you're throwing wild guesses!

Comment: What a pain. I've only ever used MSTest with Team Build/TFS, and NUnit for any other CI system. So I guess the answer is "use NUnit." :)